# Using Mint.com to pull and validate data from my ING Direct account

Tags: import, mint.com

How can I get mint.com to work correctly with my ING Direct account?

For the life of me I can't get it to validate and pull the data down correctly, is there some trick to it?

Seems like their screen scraping isn't working correctly.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the problem or give more details?

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: Could this question be written in a more general way?

Comment: I need more details so I can replicate the problem from here. Like your account number ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here is **[an instruction](http://www.ehow.com/how_4901391_ing-direct-account-mintcom.html)** of adding ING Direct account (by eHow).

And, seems that some people are having the **[same problem](http://satisfaction.mint.com/mint/topics/ing_direct_account_cannot_be_added?from_gsfn=true)** as you.
So, in case the above instruction didn't help, below is the **solution suggested by mint.com**.

> Stephen_Mann, Official Rep, replied on January 12, 2010 16:32
>
> We have been seeing very good success rates over the past month. If you are having problems our first recommendation is to **try outside of normal business hours in the US**, for example before 7am PST and after 5pm PST. Otherwise, please file your issue directly with Mint Customer Service as we are not experiencing any ING wide issues at this time

Answer (score 3):

Did you follow the steps here?

http://satisfaction.mint.com/mint/topics/ing_direct_account

Comment: I tried that, but still couldn't get it updating... I'll try again. Upvote for the link though.